# how to understand the function of "__swtich_ to" for contex-switch in the ARM linux

Tags: linux, arm, context-switch

I am trying to understand how the context switch of linux works which is based on the ARM.

So i want to understand following codes.

ENTRY(__switch_to)

```
add ip, r1, #TI_CPU_SAVE
ldr r3, [r2, #TI_TP_VALUE]
stmia   ip!, {r4 - sl, fp, sp, lr}  @ Store most regs on stack

ldr r6, [r2, #TI_CPU_DOMAIN]
strex   r5, r4, [ip]            @ Clear exclusive monitor

mcr p15, 0, r3, c13, c0, 3      @ set TLS register

mov r4, #0xffff0fff
str r3, [r4, #-15]          @ TLS val at 0xffff0ff0

mcr p15, 0, r6, c3, c0, 0       @ Set domain register
mov r5, r0
add r4, r2, #TI_CPU_SAVE
ldr r0, =thread_notify_head
mov r1, #THREAD_NOTIFY_SWITCH
bl  atomic_notifier_call_chain
mov r0, r5
ldmia   r4, {r4 - sl, fp, sp, pc}   @ Load all regs saved previously
```

I understand that these codes are used for storing cpu-context for current process and restoring cpu-context for next process which will be current process. But it doesn’t save and restore about ip, r1, r2, r3, r4, especially about cpsr(Current Program Status Register).

I think that it should save and restore the cpsr register for Context Switch. But it doesn’t save the cpsr in the above code. I don’t understand this. I am struggling with this question for a week. But I could not find the answer. It would be very grateful for somebody to give me the answer.

Comment: ARM32 has *banked registers*. The `CPSR` is saved into `SPSR` upon exception entry, and restored by exception return. I'd advise reading the architecture reference manual for more information.

Comment: _"I think that it should save and restore the cpsr register for Context Switch"_ - why do you think that? This is switching the kernel-side context of a task; who's to say if it's even a user thread at all? Anyone who's called `schedule()` _within_ the kernel isn't going to expect the argument registers and condition flags to be preserved anyway. Sounds like you're probably conflating this with `ret_to_user()`.

Comment: First thanks for your comment. i'm not sure that there are only user processes in the linux. if so, i think it's ok not to save cpsr. then system call handler(svc handler) does save and restore the cpsr like "ret_to_user"  using kernel stack. but there is the case of context switch between these kernel processes if there were more than one kernel process. so i thought that it needs to save and restore the CPSR. how do you think of this?

Comment: In addition to above, I think that the CPSR needs to preserve between context-switch. Because some ARM instruction with a condition code is only executed if the condition code flags in the CPSR meet the specified condition.

Answer (score 3):

When [`context_switch()` calls `switch_to()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c?v=4.7#L2819), it's just a regular function call. The ABI doesn't require r0-r3, r12 or the condition flags in CPSR to be preserved over a function call, thus they don't need to be saved in the context of the calling task, because it won't care what they are when it eventually gets rescheduled and picks up again upon returning from `switch_to()`.

Point is, the `cpu_context` in `thread_info`, which is what's being switched here, is the *kernel* state of whatever ended up calling into `__schedule()`. The actual (userspace) *process* state<sup>*</sup>, i.e. r0-r15, SPSR, etc. is in the task's `pt_regs` - that state is saved immediately upon entry to the kernel (see e.g. `vector_swi`) and restored upon exit (`ret_to_user`) in the manner you would expect.

<sub>* Assuming there is one, i.e. the calling context isn't a kernel thread.</sub>

Comment: Thank for your commenting again. 
I understand that the arguments register (R0 ~R3) and IP (R12) need not to be preserved.
But I don’t still understand that the condition flags in CPSR to be preserved over a function call.

Comment: The fact is that the CPSR does not require to be preserved between context-switch because the linux works well. I might be wrong or missing something. 
Anyway I have read the ABI Documents as you have advised me to.
Very close comment is that “Any veneer inserted must preserve the contents of all register except IP(r12) and the condition code flags” <== 5.3.1.1 Use of IP by the linker

Comment: Despite referring to ABI document, I don’t still understand. And I tried to disassemble the vmlinux. But I can not find the answer. Could you explain in detail about your comment that is “the condition flags in CPSR to be preserved over a function call.” I really want to know about this.
and another question is.... Do you agree that there is a case of context switch between kernel processes. In this case, should it be required not to save the cpsr? I might be wrong or missing something. It would be helpful to give me the advice or the answer.
Thanks In advance.

Comment: From section  5.1.1 of the AAPCS: _"The N, Z, C, V and Q bits (bits 27-31) and the GE[3:0] bits (bits 16-19) are undefined on entry to or return from a public interface"_. There's nothing kernel-specific about this; just disassemble "hello world" and see that that doesn't save the CPSR across function calls either.

Comment: i thnik that we doesn't have to save cpsr over a function call. it normally does not. because it's not related to context switch. i think that i have to find another reason.

Comment: You don't have to find another reason, you just have to comprehend that the thing being context-switched here _is a function call_.