# Why CPSR register is not saved during function call in ARM ABI?

Tags: assembly, arm, abi

Suppose I change the CPSR register in the caller fucntion by instruction like `SUBS R0, R0, #1`, where `R0` is exactly equals to 1, then call a function using `beq cpsr_test`. In the callee function, the `Z` flag of `CPSR` is still set, right? Then callee function's behavior is affected by caller, so why all programs do not save `CPSR` during function call(even context switch)?

caller/callee example:

```
caller  mov     r0, #1
        subs    r0, r0, #1 // Z flag set 
        b       callee

callee  mov     r2, #3
        // something here that have not update cpsr
        beq     label_1    // caller's Z flag is set
        b       label_2

label_1
label_2
```

kernel space context switch example(not save cpsr either):

```
/* arm_context_switch(addr_t *old_sp, addr_t new_sp) */
FUNCTION(arm_context_switch)
/* save non callee trashed supervisor registers */
/* spsr and user mode registers are saved and restored in the iframe by exceptions.S */
push    { r4-r11, lr }

/* save old sp */
str     sp, [r0]

/* load new regs */
mov     sp, r1
pop     { r4-r11, lr }
bx      lr
```

I saw this post: [how to understand the function of “__swtich_ to” for contex-switch in the ARM linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140898/how-to-understand-the-function-of-swtich-to-for-contex-switch-in-the-arm-li), I know that `R0-R3` is not need to saved saved because of contention, but still can't get the point of not saving `CPSR`. Help please.

Comment: _"Then callee function's behavior is affected by caller"_ - how, exactly? If the callee's behaviour relies on the implicit state of the flags, then that callee doesn't comply with the AAPCS ABI anyway (which says "[the condition flags] are undefined on entry to or return from a public interface."), making the question moot. The remaining question is tautological; the CPSR doesn't need to be saved at a public interface under the AAPCS, because the definition of the AAPCS says it doesn't.

Comment: @Notlikethat Say caller disable irq and fiq, then callee's interrupt status is disabled? This always happends when one call the context switch function, if the cpsr is not saved, the new task's irq status is same to the old one.

Comment: Where in the C language (or other users of the ABI) does the language or th e user pass alu flags from one function to another?

Comment: context switches are not part of the language.  they are target/system specific and handled as such, the interrupt that ultimately drives the context switch saves the flags at that level and the context swtich code itself has to preserve and replace the system, all the registers including the flags/cpsr.  and will for it to work

Comment: @dwelch Hi, I find the context switch of lk is really simple, it do not save the cpsr  register either, do you know why? https://github.com/littlekernel/lk/blob/master/arch/arm/arm/asm.S#L37

Comment: @dwelch CPSR is global available, so, they should be saved by callee just like r4-r11? It is my wild guess anyway.

Comment: there is no reason to save them for a caller or calee.  Unless the compiler implementation itself which is implementation specific for some reason wants to preserve them across calls.  And so far as I know no compiler does that, they deal with their conditionals, then setup for a call, after the return if there are any more conditionals they do those.   The arm design is such that switching modes to/from arm/thumb is handled by BX and others, so you dont need to preserve the mode you were in.  There is no reason for the compiler to ever save the cpsr.

Comment: only target specific application specific code cares about preserving the cpsr.  The cpsr is not globally available I dont think that user level can do mrs/msr instructions correct?  depends on the core and/or architecture perhaps.  or compile time implementation (of the core) perhaps.

Comment: @elinx just to add to comments above: don't mix the context switch and the function call: they are completely different stories.

Comment: @Serge my bad, there seems two different context switches: context switch  triggered by interrupt(or exception) and context switch triggerd by function call. I can understand that CPSR(or SPSR) backup system by ARM when the execution mode changes.If the execution mode is not changed, it's just like a function call I thought(see the code I added above, thx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs running on ARM generally follow the [ARM calling convention](http://www.toves.org/books/armsub/#s3).

> parameters are passed by placing the parameter values into registers R0 through R3 before calling the subroutine, and a subroutine returns a value by placing it into R0 before returning. [...] we'd place any additional parameters onto the stack before entering the subroutine (with the earlier parameters pushed last onto the stack, so that the fifth parameter is on the stack's top (referenced by SP).
>
> Each subroutine is allowed to alter R0 through R3 as it wishes; but if it uses R4 through R12, it must restore them to their previous values. It must also restore the stack pointer R13, effectively removing everything from the stack. It may change the link pointer R14.

Note that no mention is made of the flags register: CPSR.
Even a more formal document like The [ARM-THUMB Procedure Call Standard](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs414/2001fa/armcallconvention.pdf) doesn't.
It is implied that flags are not saved between function calls.

When doing a context switch, CPSR is saved [as can be seen in the ARM documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471c/Cjaebbeh.html).